# How to add an object constructor into an empty array that is within another object

Tags: javascript

How do arrays within an object receive data from another object, and will creating an array value of a property still make that property an object? (Confusing)

For example,

```
function example(red, blue){
    this.red1 = red;
    this.blue1 = blue;
}
var colors = new example("Red", "Blue");

//Object 2, 
var colorShapes = {triangle: blue, square: []};

//My attempt
var array1 = colorShapes.square.push(colors);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate arrays within objects (or objects within arrays, or any mix thereof) the same way you would manipulate an object or an array normally.  You only need to be able to reference it.

So in your example, `colorShapes.square` evaluates to an array, and that array can be manipulated in the same way that any array could be manipulated.

Your question is a little confusing, so please feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

First, in colorShapes it should be `triangle: "blue"`

Second, push returns the length of the array.  You want to just run `colorShapes.square.push(colors)`

Now colorShapes.square[0] evaluates to your object `colors`

Are you familiar with the chrome console?  Here is a screenshot of the code we execute, and the structure afterwards:

[image: Chrome Console Screenshot]

Comment: So push wouldn't add "red" and "blue" into colorShapes.square?

Comment: push will add whatever parameters you specify.  Since you specify `colors` you push into the array the object which has "red" and "blue" as properties.

Comment: As you can see in the example I added, colorShapes is an object with `triangle: "blue"` and `square: Array[1]` as key value pairs.  We open up square, and it shows us the numerical indicies in the array.  We open up 0 and we see that we have an instance of example, which has the key/value pairs `blue1: "Blue"`, and `red1: "Red"`

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused how did you insert Blue and Red into the square: Array[1]} I'm unaware of chrome console.

Comment: Right click any webpage, select "Inspect Element" and toggle the console (one of the tabs) if you're in Chrome.  You can run your code in there and when you console.log an object you can open it up.  The push operation places the entire object into the array.